# Unable to set custom headers on spring-boot to prevent cache control

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I noticed that my application is not working well in IE because each time user tries to refresh the data, he gets code 304 from the server
I made sure that my front end is sending two headers in each request

> 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
>           Pragma : 'no-cache'

when i checked the request i noticed the following, the custom headers are not there!!
[image: missing headers]

UPDATE -response headers

[image]

i assumed i might be missing something on my spring-boot V1.53
so i added the following things

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.debug("Proceeding to configure http security");

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint).and()
                .addFilterBefore(waffleFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/dashboard").hasAnyAuthority(allowedRoles);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/read/**").hasAnyAuthority(allowedRoles);




        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").denyAll();

        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Cache-Control","no-cache"));
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Pragma","no-cache"));




        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

    }
```

but that didn't change anything
i tried to add the following properties

```
spring.resources.chain.cache=true
security.headers.cache=false
```

and still no headers
i tested with chrome and IE but in nither i can see my custom headers

its worth to mention that my front-end is angular4 and when i test it locally
using ng serve, i can see the two custom headers

Comment: You're looking at the *request* headers there, in the screenshot.

Comment: yes... someone i don't know who is removing them....

Comment: Huh? I said you are looking at the **request** headers. Those are sent by the browser to the server. `Cache-control` is a **response** header. Did you check those?

Comment: i added a screenshot, but nevertheless, as i wrote on testing env, i see the headers on the request yet when i deploy on tomcat with spring-boot i don't i don't understand what/who can remove the headers from the request